# R: How to divide columns in matrix by a vector ？

Tags: r

```
matrix <- matrix(1:20,nrow=4,ncol=5)
(matrix <- matrix(1:20,nrow=4,ncol=5))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20

(vector <-c(2,4,3,5,2)) 

[1] 2 4 3 5 2
```

I want to divide each column in matrix by the corresponding element in vector,like all values in column1 divided by 2, all values in column2 divided by 4, etc.

```
 > (matrix/vector)
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]
    [1,]  0.5 2.50  1.8 4.33  4.25
    [2,]  0.5 3.00  5.0 2.80  6.00
    [3,]  1.0 1.75  5.5 7.50  3.80
    [4,]  0.8 2.67  3.0 8.00 10.00
```

Divide the matrix by vector directly seems not available, very appreciated if I get any useful answer.

Comment: `t(t(matrix)/vector)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfect use case for `sweep` -

```
sweep(matrix, MARGIN = 2, STATS = vector, `/`)

     [,1] [,2]     [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.5 1.25 3.000000  2.6  8.5
[2,]  1.0 1.50 3.333333  2.8  9.0
[3,]  1.5 1.75 3.666667  3.0  9.5
[4,]  2.0 2.00 4.000000  3.2 10.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!That's a easiest way.